# Bash script - dialog checklist issue

Tags: bash, dialog

I'm trying to to write a bash script to automate the installation of my packages. So the idea is to read a .csv file (packages.csv) like this one:

```
pkg,Description,option
wget,file downloader,on
curl,tool to transfer data from or to a server,on
nano,text editor for Unix-like computing systems,off
emacs,An extensible customizable free/libre text editor — and more,on
```

build an array for each column (without header) and then pass the arrays to a dialog checklist.

```
#!/bin/bash

input="packages.csv"
while IFS=',' read -r col1 col2 col3
do 
    for a in $col1; do
        array_col1+=("$a") 
    done

    for b in $col2; do
        array_col2+=("$b")
    done

    for c in $col3; do
        array_col3+=("$c")
    done        

done < "$input"

array1=("${array_col1[@]:1}")
array2=("${array_col2[@]:1}")
array3=("${array_col3[@]:1}")

let num=${#array2[*]}-1

for i in $(seq 0 $num); do
    list[i]=$(echo ${array1[i]} ${array2[i]} ${array3[i]})
done

OPTION=$(dialog --checklist "Choose packages:" \
10 60 4 \
${list[*]})
exitstatus=$?
if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]; then
    echo "$OPTION"
else
    echo "Cancel"
fi
```

I did get it working at some point but without any spaces in the description. After I did some changes in order to include the spaces it doesn't work at all. How can I fix it?
Actually in my .csv file I have more than 3 columns but bash checklist expects 3 arguments. Is it possible to somehow include them in the checklist?

Comment: Have you considered using something like [puppet](https://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/install-multiple-packages.html) instead? The link has an example of your exact use case.

Comment: No, puppet seems to be an overkill for this simple case.

Comment: What is `for a in $col1; do` for? And the same for `b` and `c`? I think when you do it for `b`, `$col2` undergoes word splitting with standard `IFS`; then you get multiple `b`-s while still parsing a single line.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski: Fill the 3 arrays

Comment: I have found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146241/error-with-linux-whiptail-dialog-arguments-from-bash-variable which works. The middle argument is within single quotes and left and right arguments are not. This must be the problem but I don't know how to fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

input="packages.csv"
while IFS=',' read -r col1 col2 col3 dummy
do
   array+=("$col1")
   array+=("$col2")
   array+=("$col3")
done < <(tail -n +2 "$input")

option=$(dialog --checklist --output-fd 1 "Choose packages:" 10 60 4 "${array[@]}")

exitstatus=$?
if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]; then
    echo "$option"
else
    echo "Cancel"
fi
```

Main changes:

- `tail -n +2 "$input"` to strip the header;
- `dummy` variable to allow more than three columns (extra columns don't matter to `dialog`);
- one `array` variable to build input for `dialog` instead of many that pass data in a crippled way;
- `"${array[@]}"` as a proper way to pass array as command line arguments in this case;
- `--output-fd 1` explained [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/704643/693277) (there are better, more robust solutions there);
- lowercase variables per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).

---

> Actually in my `.csv` file I have more than 3 columns but bash checklist expects 3 arguments. Is it possible to somehow include them in the checklist?

What for? True, `dialog --checklist` expects them three by three. Keep it tidy. I guess maybe you need more columns for your code that comes *after* `dialog`. Consider this: when `dialog` successfully returns identifiers from the first column and you have them in `$option`, parse its output like this:

```
for package in $option; do … ; done
```

(For this to work your first column in `packages.csv` cannot contain spaces etc.)

This way you can do something for every chosen package. Inside this loop you can read as many columns as you need anew, but first `grep` for the proper line:

```
IFS=',' read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 dummy < <(grep "^${package}," "$input")
```

(Hint: investigate `read -a`, see `help read`). And then, still inside the loop, do the rest of your job.